# Using UPS with USB driver on Hyper-V Core

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, ups

My setup:

- HP ML350 G6
- HP R/T2200 UPS that has a USB
  connection
- Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2
  (bare metal hypervisor)
- SBS2008 running in a VM
- Windows Server 2008 R2 running in a VM
- Other VMs for development work

I want to manage the UPS using HP Power Manager but I don't think it is Hyper-V aware.

Any suggestions on how to manage the UPS?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Couldn't find a way to do this by software only ... hardware solution is a USB server (I used a NetComm NP3680, cost A$125) with it's driver and then I setup the HP Power Manager (web server) on one of my VM's.

Hope this helps someone with similar problems with USB devices on VM's.